# Why are my videos and images not showing up?

Tags: aframe

I have an image or video on AWS S3 or somewhere on the Internet.

I tried to apply a texture to a box by referencing the image path directly:

```
<a-scene>
  <a-box src="https://blah.com/sometexture.png"></a-box>
</a-scene>
```

But nothing shows up. I get some console errors about no image and CORS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> With A-Frame 0.3.0, you no longer need to manually specify crossorigin. It will automatically be set on assets that require CORS.

https://aframe.io/faq/#why-does-my-asset-e-g-image-video-model-not-loading

Generally, the issue is due to CORS. Because all assets are fetched via XHR, you will need to enable allow CORS headers on your asset. This is very common if you serve from S3. Once you have enabled CORS, you need to set `crossorigin` flag on your assets:

```
<a-scene>
  <a-assets>
    <img id="texture" crossorigin src="https://blah.com/sometexture.png">
    <video id="texture2" crossorigin src="https://blah.com/sometexture.mp4">
  </a-assets>

  <a-box src="#texture"></a-box>
  <a-video src="#texture2"></a-video>
</a-scene>
```

We do have a free uploader provided by UploadCare. It is down at the moment, but later you will be able to upload here and get CORSed assets for free https://aframe.io/aframe/examples/_uploader/

**On iOS Safari**, if the image still doesn't load, you may have previously loaded it without `crossorigin` and it is cached. Try clearing the browser cache.